# SDWebImage always returns error code 401

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage in my Swift 2.0 project. When running on iOS 9 it always returns the following error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=401 "(null)"
```

Using SDWebImage to load image from server

```
cell.backgroundImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://..."), placeholderImage: placeholderImg, options: SDWebImageOptions.RetryFailed, completed: {(image, error, type, url) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
      // do something with image          
   }
})
```

As it's an http:// request and running on iOS 9, I've also added this to my Info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the server needed authentication to request this image resource. That's why `SDWebImage` correctly returned a 401 error code.

Comment: This is what [401](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) http code is all about